# Is it possible to selectively apply minimum depth in a find command?

Tags: find

I have a file hierarchy like:

```
data
├── debug.log
├── messages
│   ├── msg001.txt
│   ├── msg002.txt
│   └── msg003.txt
└── pictures
    ├── msg002
    │   └── pic001.jpg
    └── msg003
        ├── pic001.jpg
        └── pic002.jpg
```

I would like to find all the files, and all the directories below the top two levels (data, data/messages, and data/pictures). All the things that are not a part of the fixed structure of the hierarchy, if that makes sense.

Can i do this with a single find invocation?

I can find the files:

```
$ find data -type f | sort
data/debug.log
data/messages/msg001.txt
data/messages/msg002.txt
data/messages/msg003.txt
data/pictures/msg002/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003/pic002.jpg
```

And i can find the directories:

```
$ find data -mindepth 2 -type d | sort
data/pictures/msg002
data/pictures/msg003
```

But i can't combine these, because -mindepth is an option, not a test:

```
$ find data -type f -o \( -mindepth 2 -type d \) | sort
find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it). Please specify options before other arguments.

data/messages/msg001.txt
data/messages/msg002.txt
data/messages/msg003.txt
data/pictures/msg002
data/pictures/msg002/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003
data/pictures/msg003/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003/pic002.jpg
```

(note that data/debug.log is not found here)

Is there any way to consider the depth in the hierarchy as a real test?

The best kludge i can think of is using a regexp on the path to recognise the top two levels of directories:

```
$ find data -type f -o \( -type d -regextype posix-extended \! -regex 'data(/[^/]+)?' \) | sort
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `-mindepth` is a non-standard extension (initially from GNU `find` but since added to a few other implementations). Contrary to `-maxdepth`, it's easy to emulate with standard predicates though. For instance `LC_ALL=C find . -path './*/*'` emulates GNU's `find . -mindepth 2`.

So, here:

```
LC_ALL=C find data '(' -type d -path '*/*/*' -o -type f ')' -print0 |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

(you can't pipe the output of `find` to `sort` unless you use NUL-delimited records btw as file paths can be made of more than one line. `-print0` and `-z` are GNU extensions, `-print0` now common (and soon POSIX), `-z` less so).

Comment: How does `LC_ALL=C` help in that command? What is the corner case it deals with?

Comment: @aviro `*` matches zero or more *characters*, while file paths are made of 1 or more *bytes* other  than 0 which don't have to make up characters in the user's locale. For instance, with GNU `find` on a GNU system (using the GNU libc's `fnmatch()`), in a locale using the UTF-8 charmap `-name '*'`  would not match on a file created with `touch $'Ste\351phane'` (which happens to be Stéphane encoded in iso8859-1 aka latin1 instead of UTF-8) or `touch $'\x7f\x80'` (file names don't have to be text)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to consider the depth in the hierarchy as a real test?

There is in [FreeBSD find](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)), it has `-depth N` also as a condition:

```
% find data -type f -o -depth +1 -type d |sort
data/debug.log
data/messages/msg001.txt
data/messages/msg002.txt
data/messages/msg003.txt
data/pictures/msg002
data/pictures/msg002/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003
data/pictures/msg003/pic001.jpg
data/pictures/msg003/pic002.jpg
```

(and yes, that can be easily confused with the `-depth` option.)

If you know the set of directories that are part of the "fixed structure" (and IMO you should, if the structure is indeed fixed), you could just exclude those:

```
% find data ! -path data ! -path data/messages ! -path data/pictures
...
```

or the same with grep:

```
% find data | grep -vEe '^(data|data/(pictures|messages))$'
...
```

(since you're already using the default output format of `find`, instead of `find -print0`, your filenames likely don't contain newlines)

Comment: There is not *one* BSD `find`. `find` is different between different BSDs. That `-depth [+-]n` AFAIK was introduced by FreeBSD. It's not available in NetBSD or OpenBSD for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yep, I'm actually not surprised. It was sloppy of me not to check.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the prettiest approach, but you could do something as follows with GNU `find`:

```
find data -printf '%d\0%y\0%p\n' | awk -F '\0' '$2 == "f" || $2 == "d" && $1 >= 2 {print $3}'
```

`find` with the `-printf` flag will print the following fields (separated by the null character - `\0`)

```
  %d     File's depth in the directory tree; 0 means the file is a starting-point.
  %y     File's type (like in ls -l), U=unknown type (shouldn't happen)
  %p     File's name.
```

Then the `awk` command will print the names for all the files (`$2 == "f"`) and directories whose depth equals or greater than 2 (`$2=="d" && $1 >= 2`).

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of the rawhide (rh) program used in this response (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

With *rh*, you can do it like this:

```
rh data 'f || (d && depth >= 2)'
```

This searches in the `data` directory for files (`f`), and for directories (`d`) whose depth is at least 2 (`depth >= 2`).

It works on Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, macOS, Solaris, and Cygwin.